# How to use "pyrogram.raw.functions.messages.GetScheduledHistory"

Tags: python, telegram, schedule, pyrogram

Can you tell me how to get scheduled posts in telegram? I wanted to make posts in telegram by adding 4 hours to a scheduled post and making a new post in the queue, but I can't get the scheduled posts themselves. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.raw import functions
from config import TELEGRAM_API_ID, TELEGRAM_API_HASH, CHANNEL_NAME

def main():
with Client(CHANNEL_NAME, api_id=TELEGRAM_API_ID, api_hash=TELEGRAM_API_HASH) as app:
peer = app.resolve_peer('@mychannel')
result = (functions.messages.GetScheduledHistory(peer=peer, hash=0))
print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

The response I get is:

```
{
"_": "functions.messages.GetScheduledHistory",
"peer": {
"_": "types.InputPeerChannel",
"channel_id": 1917338710,
"access_hash": -4931981137912508238
},
"hash": 0
}
```